# Como terminar el proceso de una función nativa en php en un determinado tiempo

Tags: php, script

Estoy creando un script en php para descargar un video.

Resulta que el servidor en donde esta el video limita la velocidad de descarga después de 5 segundos, pensé en hacer un bucle en donde se haga una petición al servidor cada 5 segundos, pero tengo un problema a la hora de usar la función **file_get_contens**, no se como cerrar el proceso de esta función.

Comment: Te recomiendo leer el manual https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.file-get-contents.php para que te des cuenta de su funcionamiento

Comment: Por lo que puedo entender, agregándole dos parámetros mas a la función puede finalizar por ella misma: `file_get_contens($param1.$param2,$param3)`